# Why do the chat messages have deletion/editing time in chatrooms?

Tags: discussion, chat

In chatrooms, we have only 2-3 minutes(approx.) to delete/edit a message we posted. Why is there this kind of restriction in deletion/editing of messages? Why can't we delete/edit them later?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100682/can-we-have-more-than-2-minutes-to-edit-comments-in-chat/236849#236849 (and related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234148/a-state-of-grace-period/236850#236850)